# JSTestDriver coverage eclipse plugin

Tags: javascript, eclipse, unit-testing, code-coverage, js-test-driver

I'm using JSTestDriver Eclipse plug-in and I want to install the coverage plugin:
does anybody know how to get it working in Eclipse?

thanks in advance

Other things to note: I am under Win XP 64 bits, 
Eclipse version:
Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.
Version: Helios Service Release 2
Build id: 20110218-0911

The plugin part in the .conf file is:

```
plugin:
  - name: "coverage"
    jar: "F:/eclipse/plugins/coverage-1.3.4.b.jar"
    module: "com.google.jstestdriver.coverage.CoverageModule"
```

Comment: What problems are you having with it, exactly?

Comment: Simple: 
when the coverage plugin is configured in the .conf file,
I run the test, the message "run js-test-driver Tests Job" appears in the progress view and that's it. Nothing else happens. If I open Chrome's JS console, all I can see is a sequence of "current command noop". 
No way to stop the task from running in Eclipse: I have to kill Eclipse from task manager.
Also, no .dat coverege file is created.

Comment: Today I have tried to launch some tests and patiently waited to see whether eclipse was actually stuck.
I've found this in the error log: 
"An internal error occurred during: "Run js-test-driver Tests Job"
null
Error
Thu Jun 07 09:35:03 CEST 2012
An internal error occurred during: "Run js-test-driver Tests Job".
some of the details:
while scanning a double-quoted scalar
found unknown escape character p(112)

any hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The coverage.jar is NOT an eclipse plugin, it is a JsTestDriver plugin. The JsTestDriver ecplise plugin does not support testcoverage. Your tests fail because your coverage plugin must be located in the same folder or a subfolder relative to your configfile.

For example

```
plugin:
- name: "coverage"
  jar: "plugins/coverage-1.3.4.b.jar"
  module: "com.google.jstestdriver.coverage.CoverageModule"
```

If you want to know the testcoverage for your project, you should download JsTestDriver-1.3.4.b.jar from http://code.google.com/p/js-test-driver/downloads/list.

Then run a command like

```
java -jar JsTestDriver-1.3.4.b.jar --browser <browserpath> --port 4224 --tests all
```

in your console.

For this, your configfile and the JsTestDriver.jar should be in the same folder.

Comment: thanks to you I have managed to run JSTestDriver with the coverage plugin.
I was just wondering whether the coverage result is written into a file or just output to the console.
Or is there a parameter to set to write the file?